# Visual Studio never makes a new line when receiving from Arduino

Tags: c#, arduino, serial-port

I made a simple serial monitor using WinForms with C#, and it works completely fine except that data received all goes to the same line, even if they are not sent at the same time.

RXWindow is my textbox where I plan to read out the serial data it gives.

```
String RxString;
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) {
    RxString = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
    this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));
}

private void DisplayText(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    RXWindow.AppendText(RxString);
}
```

It always comes through like this (if I just send "testing" repeatedly).
[image]

What can I change so that it inserts newlines with all new data. Do I just need to adapt the Arduino code to send a newline character as well? I figured that since the Arduino IDE's serial monitor receives with newlines fine, that I wouldn't need to change anything either though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use:

```
RXWindow.AppendText(RxString + Environment.NewLine);
```

or

```
RXWindow.AppendText(RxString + "\r\n");
```

Comment: @Trevader2413 If you send the string in one piece, it doesn't guarantee that you will receive the string in one piece.